# Any way to make the local variables automatically display in the watch window of CodeBlocks nightly builds?

Tags: c++, c, ide, codeblocks

In CodeBlocks 10.05, it's easy. Just right-click on the watch window-->watch '*this.'
But in the nightly builds, no way to do that?

In the codeblocks wiki, I see `"In latest nightly builds: The automatic inclusion of local variables and function arguments have not been reimplemented. Sorry for the inconvenience. "`.

If that's true, then really very inconvenient, right?